# How to remove a fragment from a container with animations?

Tags: android, animation, fragment, back

I have the following fragment in my activity -

```
val checkoutBillingShippingFragment = CheckoutBillingShippingFragment(authorizationToken, object : CheckoutBillingShippingFragment.OnCurrentStageCompleteListener {
            override fun goToNextCheckoutStage(stageToGo: CheckoutStages) {
                Toast.makeText(this@CheckoutActivity, "Next stage is - $stageToGo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                currentCheckoutStage = stageToGo
                if (stageToGo == CheckoutStages.SHIPPING_ADDRESS) {
                    mPresenter.goToShippingStage()
                }

            }
        })
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_checkout_billing_address_container, checkoutBillingShippingFragment)
                .addToBackStack("")
                .commit()
```

In the relevant scenario I am calling `activity?.onBackPressed()`

The fragment is being closed as expected.

I want it to close with animations, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

FragmentTransaction has a method `setCustomAnimations(int, int)`.

Here are an example with anim Android resources:

`setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)`

You can create custom animations in this anim res and set to enter animation, exit animation.